# Avoid overlap in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have the following layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/itemKey"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:text="Recipient:"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/itemValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/itemKey"
    tools:text="loooooooooonnnnnnngemmmmmmmmaaaaaaaiiilll@gmail.com"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is how it shows up:

[image: Actual]

It should really be:

[image: Ideal]

What do I need to fix this? I've tried using guidelines and horizontal bias, and also tried constraining it with RelativeLayout instead of a ConstraintLayout, but nothing has helped so far.

Comment: You can either use 0dp for width of your `TextView` or use `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"` to enforce the constraints.
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#wrap_content-:-enforcing-constraints-added-in-1.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try setting `itemValue` width to 0 and use `layout_constraintStart_toEndOf` instead:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemValue"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/itemKey"
        tools:text="loooooooooonnnnnnngemmmmmmmmaaaaaaaiiilll@gmail.com"/>
```

You may need to use `android:gravity="right|end"` if you intend to align the text to the end.

Comment: Thank you, Aaron. Although there are other answers which worked as well, your suggestion to use the `gravity` flag clinched it for me.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't care about having the second view's width be `wrap_content`, you can make some small changes. Make the width `0dp` instead of `wrap_content` and change `app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf` to `app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf` (with the same value). This will make the view always be exactly as large as the remaining horizontal space:

[image]

If you need `wrap_content` behavior, then you can do the same as above but additionally add these two attributes:

```
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
```

[image]

[image]

Here it is all together:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/itemValue"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/itemKey"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
    tools:text="loooooooooonnnnnnngemmmmmmmmaaaaaaaiiilll@gmail.com" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem. If you want the text to take the next line you can remove the `maxLines=1` condition.

```
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemKey"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:text="Recipient:"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemValue"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/itemKey"
        tools:text="loooooooooonnnnnnngemmmmmmmmaaaaaaaiiilll@gmail.com"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```